# End to End encryption using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, cryptojs, sjcl

I'm working on a web app which will have very serious and sensitive data in it. How do I use Codeigniter on the backend and on the frontend some other library to encrypt data throughout the GET and SET process ( Client server encrypted )

https://mega.nz/#info

In this website they say they encrypt end to end. I do not know how to implement this.

Any thoughts on this please ? Any security gurus come up and give me a hand please

Comment: I think they have used js

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Mega's encryption work for sharing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346054/how-does-megas-encryption-work-for-sharing)

Comment: I need to know how to use same encryptions it with Codeigntier

Comment: If you want it end-to-end then this has nothing to do with codeigniter, because it has to be done on the client sied as Uzumaki already said.

Comment: How do i accept the encrypted data on the frontend on the backend ( Codeigniter ) ?

Answer (score -2):

I encrypt all my sensitive data (like ids, passwords, serial_numbers, etc.) from the backend to the front end, and when i retrieve data from the front end i just decrypt it, this way all clients that inspects my code in the front end, doesn't know the meaning of some parts, all this with some functions in a helper file, i don't know if this is what you are searching for

Comment: are you using Codeigniter ? So what library do you use to encrypt the data on the frontend ? and how do you share the encrypt code/key ?

Comment: This doesn't even remotely being to answer how to implement end-to-end encryption.